# Tilde symbol does not display correctly in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I wanted to type `cd~` into PowerShell to move to my home directory, however when I pressed SHIFT and the tilde keys the output is `cd˜`, so instead of the big regular tilde symbol `~`, I got small superscript tilde symbol `˜` I can type the tilde symbol in other applications, the problem only occurs when I use PowerShell or cmd.exe, I'm using ENG(Canada) US Keyboard, Window 8.1 and PowerShell version 4.0

The closest topic I found on the site that cover a problem similar to mine is this one [Tilde not recognized in Mac terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9068470/tilde-not-recognized-in-mac-terminal) but it's for MAC and I am using Window 8.1

Any suggestion on how I can fix the problem?

Comment: hmm have you tried another keyboard layout? works fine for me with the german one  (although for me its alt gr + tilde key instead of shift)

Comment: Does it actually make a difference? I mean, does powershell not set the location to your home folder when you do `cd ~`

Answer (score 0):

This is probably caused by your keyboard settings ( input services in control panel ). You need to find offending service and remove it.

Until you find it, you can fix this with AHK hotstrings :

```
::˜::~
```